# Interview: Appointment reservations

Tags: python, interview-questions

I have received this question during an interview I did earlier, but I found that my solution might not be correct. And I would like to know whatever there is a better way to solve this.

Question:

> Lots of people are making a reservation for appointments
>
> Writes a function to let people make appointments reservation before 
>   attending the appointment. When a time-slot is reserved 
>   (already booked), do not let any user double-book and make overlap         reservation in the same time-slot.
>
> Reservation takes (as an example)
>
> - personA: 9:00 -> 11:00 tomorrow -> successful
> - personB: 9:00 -> 10:00 tomorrow -> fail
> - personC: 13:00 -> 14:00 tomorrow -> successful
> - personA: 17:00 -> 18:00 tomorrow -> fail because personA already made reservation once
>
> **Few notes:**
>
> - Assuming reservation only for 1 specific day, 24-hrs only
> - Assuming the clock is 24-hrs with only integers
>
> **Additions - v1.1** After launching v1.0, more than half of the users do not attend their appointments. Allow a user to reserve appointments
>   twice in the same time intervals

```
ALLOW_MULTIPLE_RESERVATIONS = 2

users = {
    'alice': '1',
    'bob': '2',
}


appointments = [[9, 12], [9, 12], [13, 17]]
reservations = {}


def print_error(user, time):
    print('Cannot make reservation for user {} at {}'.format(user, time))
    return False

def reserve(user, time):

    # this case is for double reservation for the same interval
    if user in reservations:
        user_reservation = reservations[user]
        user_count = reservations[user]['count']
        user_time = reservations[user]['time']
        if user_count < ALLOW_MULTIPLE_RESERVATIONS:
            if user_time[0] == time[0] and user_time[1] == time[1]:
                reservations[user] = {
                    'time': time,
                    'count': user_count + 1,
                }
            return True
        else:
            print_error(user, time)
            return False

    # this is for first time reservation
    for t in appointments:
        if user not in reservations:
            if (time[0] >= t[0] and time[1] <= t[1]):
                t[0] = time[1]
                t[1] = t[1]
                reservations[user] = {
                    'time': time,
                    'count': 1,
                }

    # end-for

    # when we cannot find any available time interval for reservation, we simply just return False
    if user not in reservations:
        print_error(user, time)
        return False
    return True




reserve(user='alice', time=[9, 10])
reserve(user='alice', time=[9, 10]) # v1.1 this should pass
reserve(user='alice', time=[9, 10]) # v1.1 this should fail
reserve(user='bob', time=[9, 10])

print(reservations)
print(appointments)
```

Comment: what is the `appointments` list used for?